# jquery on click change class of list element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my dynamically generated lists :

```
<ul class="config-swatch-list">

   <li class='color' onclick="color_select();">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val"></a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select();">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val"></a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select();">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val"></a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select();">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val"></a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select();">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val"></a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

and the js function:

```
function color_select() {
    $('#color').click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            console.log('clicked');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is using this code when I clicked 1st `li` element, this js function add a `active` class successfully . But this does not work for 2nd, or 4th `li` element (printing `clicked` in console).So the codes only working for 1st, 3rd , and 5th `li` elements. If I double click 2nd or 4th `li` element then the code working as expected.

All I want to do is after a click change a single `li` element css class to `active` or remove `active` class if there is already existing `active` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `onclick` attributes from `<a>`. And don't wrap `click` inside other function. And also use `.color` instead of `#color`
`

```js
$('.color').click(function()
{
   if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
       console.log('clicked');
       $(this).removeClass('active');
   } else {
         $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="config-swatch-list">

   <li class='color'>
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">one</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color'>
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">two</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color'>
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">three</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' >
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">four</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color'>
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">five</a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) .. you can still use `onclick` .. and use `toggleClass()` for `active` class instead of `add/removeClass`

```js
function color_select(el) {
    $('.color').removeClass('active').filter(el).toggleClass('active'); // remove active class from the li's and toggle the class for the clicked element
}
```

```css
.active{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="config-swatch-list">

   <li class='color' onclick="color_select(this);">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">Link 1</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select(this);">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">Link 2</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select(this);">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">Link 3</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select(this);">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">Link 4</a>
   </li>
   <li class='color' onclick="color_select(this);">
        <a href="#" style="background-color: random_val">Link 5</a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

<sup>**But to be honest** personally I don't prefer to use `onclick=` using a `.click` which presented by @Maheer answer is for me much much better</sup>