# Facing issue in triggering javascript function from span with role button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I am constructing table with input type text and span with role button inside the .
I want to trigger javascript function when user clicked on span with role button.
Here is my span

```
         <th>
            <span data-field=@COLUMN_NAME class="k-filtercell" data-role="filtercell">
                  <span>
                       <input id="COLUMN_NAME" data-bind="value: value" style="width:120px" aria-label="Name" title="Name" data-text-field=@COLUMN_NAME role="textbox"  aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" >
                     <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" onclick="filterInputBtn();" tabindex="-1"></span>
                   </span>
            </span>
       </th>
```

I am triggering javascript function

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            filterInputBtn = function () {
             var inputHTML = $(this).closest('input').val();
           }
        });
```

But the click event is not getting triggered.
Please let me know how to trigger click event from span with role button

Comment: This has nothing to do with the element or its role. Just use jQuery's [built in methods for attaching events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, the correct way would be to use a `.on()` listener on the `span`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span[role=button]").on("click", function() {
    var inputHTML = $(this).prev('input').val();
    console.log(inputHTML)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>
    <span data-field=@COLUMN_NAME class="k-filtercell" data-role="filtercell">
                  <span>
                       <input id="COLUMN_NAME" data-bind="value: value" style="width:120px" aria-label="Name" title="Name" data-text-field=@COLUMN_NAME role="textbox"  aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text">
                     <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1">Span Content</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching on click event anywhere in your code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function filterInputBtn () {
         var inputHTML = $(this).closest('input').val();
       }
    });
```

In javascript you have to first use keyword "function" and then write the name of the function

Hope this will help

Comment: From the OP, in the HTML: `onclick="filterInputBtn();"`

Comment: yeah but he has written his function definition bad as I explained above in the code snippet

Comment: ...which you added after my comment, but that's okay :)

Comment: well i didn't seen that you're posting comment :) but that's okay